# Object with arrays of objects

Tags: typescript

I want to declare a variable that is an object filled with arrays of objects for example:

```js
let obj = {
    "page1"     : [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
    "page2"     : [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ],
    "dsfsfffsfs": [ {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 5} ]
}
```

How can I declare that as an interface in typescript?

Comment: This would look to be quite trivial... what difficulties are you running into in writing it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

for useState and React, try this:

```
export interface Obj {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}
```

and then:

```
 const [objList, setObjList] = useState<Obj[]>([]);
```